# Use javascript/jquery to see if items in list are due soon in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, sharepoint

I am trying to determine by date if an item is due. In my use case, my user will create an item with a date in the following format (MM/DD or 06/15). Now if the date the user chooses will fall in the next 30 days or month then it will turn red. If the date will fall within the next 60 days or less (until it reaches 30) then it will be orange and if greater than 60 they will be yellow.

so just to clarify, if my date <= 30 days from today's date then turn red and so on...

I was looking into Date.js to perform these calculations but unsure of how to get started.

What I was thinking so far was the following:

```
var _dueDate = CurrentItem.DateNeeded; //not sure if this is correct syntax for SharePoint development
var now = Date();

var nowPlus30 = new Date();
nowPlus.setDate(now.getDate() + 30);

var nowPlus90 = new Date();
nowPlus.setDate(now.getDate() + 90);

if (_dueDate == '' || !_dueDate) {
    return '';
}

and then just using the values to change the background color for example:

  if( _dueDate <= nowPlus30 ) //find the data to use to determine the color
            {
                x[i].parentNode.style.backgroundColor = 'orange'; // set the color
            }
```

but doing these for each condition has not worked so far so I think using Date.js may help but again, no idea how to proceed and because I can't use SharePoint designer to use those built in conditional statements I have to use javascript to do the operation. Have asked this previously but I think this is more of a javascript issue I am having as opposed to a SharePoint issue.

please help!

Comment: _dueDate appears to always be today's date. Are you assigning it another value somewhere else?

Comment: @Robbert, ok yeah that makes sense. The due date is supposed to be the date that the user provides in the item. So really that would be for example: CurrentItem.DateNeeded which would be in the format of 04/15.

Comment: Does 04/15 equate to 4/1/2015? Or does it mean the last day of the month? Or the middle? Why not store the date as an actual date instead of month and year only?

Comment: @Robbert, For my form the users needed the date in that format. But if in the code we could say if it in the format of 04/15 then that actually equals 04/01/2015. Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 0):

While you don't mention how you are retrieving your data from SharePoint, once you get the due date value, you can create a date object like this

```
var dueDate = '4/15';
var dParts = dueDate.split('/');
var year = ("20" + dParts[1]) * 1; //converts the string into a number
var month = dParts[0] * 1;
var _dueDate = new Date(year,month,1);
```